# logic function simplification and implementation

Tags: boolean-logic

we are searching  for the simplest implementation  of this boolean logic function :[image: ente image description herre]

you can only use this logic elements : AND,OR,NOT,XOR.
thanks in advance.

Comment: That's weird notation - can you confirm what the truth table should be ?

Comment: this is the whole task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is the required truth table:

```
 A  B  C  D  X
 0  0  0  0  1
 0  0  0  1  0
 0  0  1  0  0
 0  0  1  1  1
 0  1  0  0  0
 0  1  0  1  1
 0  1  1  0  1
 0  1  1  1  0
 1  0  0  0  0
 1  0  0  1  1
 1  0  1  0  1
 1  0  1  1  0
 1  1  0  0  0
 1  1  0  1  0
 1  1  1  0  0
 1  1  1  1  0
```

Then this seems to be the best implementation:

```
X = (A^B).(C^D) + (A'.B').(C^D)'
```

Comment: I wrote out the truth table first then isolated common terms by inspection. This is somewhat like the [Karnaugh Map](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) technique.

Comment: thanks a lot I will try to solve it on my own and check the results :).  For drawing the solution like logic elements Is there any rule from where should I start(inner or outer expressions) or it doesn't matter?

Comment: It really doesn't matter - there is a 1:1 mapping from the algebra to the gates so other than layout you can't really go wrong.